# How to create a sitemap in a <select> dropdown in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, select, sitemap, dropdown

I can't find a way to creating a sitemap from all known pages displayed as a  dropdown in Wordpress. The sitemap must be placed in the footer.

How to create a sitemap in a  dropdown in Wordpress? Because i don't want a tall list in the footer but a compact way to display the sitemap links. I use Wordpress 4.4.10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom nav walker and instead of wrapping li's in ul's you could wrap option's in select's.